# How to remove "TypeError: c is null" in Wordpress Page Edit Area

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I have a website built in wordpress CMS by using Visual Composer. When ever i Add/Edit Page content i have always got an Error.

```
TypeError: c is null

...var b=a.getWin(),c=b.getSelection();if(!(c.rangeCount<=0)){var d="SELRES_"+Math....
```

[image]

How i can remove this.

Comment: I encounter same error but only in Firefox where i am unable to save popup when editing any element. In chrome i can save the popup however, i get scrolled to the bottom of the page every time i do so.

Comment: I have the same issue.. Did anyone found solution?

Comment: same issue at my site

Comment: Facing the same error. In my case whenever I try to remove or add  VC object, the console throws the error: TypeError: c is null load-scripts.php:774:4843

Edit: Only facing this in Firefox. Chrome works fine.

Comment: Same issue, seems like a pretty big bug. Its happening to us using the modified and bundled version of Visual Composer that comes in the Jupiter theme.

Answer (score 2):

Emergency solution: don't use Firefox; if you use Opera or Chrome you will not get that error and the visual composer works.
With an older version of Opera (45.0.X) I don't get any error.

Best solution: upgrade Visual Composer.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to latest version (5.4) of WPBakery Page Builder (formerly Visual Composer) solved the problem in my case.